# New W10 build giving ~105 Mbps speeds with Full Gigabit hardware and 1 Gbps internet package

Tags: gigabit-ethernet

I have a bizarre issue.

Windows Device Manager shows Auto Negotiation is enabled.  Windows Network Status shows 1.0 Gbps Full Duplex.  This is where it gets funky though.  I just reinstalled Windows and installed the core LAN driver that came packaged with the Maximus VI Hero on the official ASUS support page.  Before I had the whole 1.0 Gbps; now, ~~(EDIT: not Xfinity home, but Speedtest by Ookla [see below addendums])~~ shows ~105 Mbps.

I switched the cable to the other port on the modem/router "combo" device (i.e. CGM4140COM by Technicolor) that I was given.  Still ~105 Mbps.  There was additional info here about my Vizio TV but it's irrelevant as, apparently, my TV can only run @ 100 Mbps Full Duplex.

Furthermore, I have the blinking orange LED indicator on my NIC as well as a solid green LED indicator.  For an Asus Maximus VI Hero, this device is built-in and is undoubtedly the Intel l217-V NIC which does not appear to have the best online documentation as to what these lights mean.  Apparently however, the blinking light would indicate just that the connection is established and is transmitting data whereas the solid LED is the speed.  The speed LED *does not blink, and is green.*  This would indicate my speed is being transmitted at *1.0 Gbps*, right?

Addendums:

I am on a 1 Gbps plan with Comcast.  It is a FTTC/N connection, so I use a coaxial splitter for cable and internet.  I bought fresh coaxial for the internet and tested the speeds using a device I ordered from Home Depot.  They reach maximum speeds on the copper.

I tested my speed using Ookla speedtest.  Comcast, Boston MA server.  It starts at around 90 Mbps and then slowly works its way to 100/101 Mbps, then ends at slightly below 107 Mbps.  I do not know why.

Upon further investigation, I realized that both ports of my modem/router are full 1.0 Gbps all around.  I saw a port running in Xfinity Home as 100 Mbps but, apparently, *this is my Vizio TV capped at 100 Mbps Full Duplex* due to its architecture.  So, my PC is definitely not, at least officially, capped at 100 Mbps in any shape or form.  As far as I can tell, anyway.

Yikes!  I received a number of downvotes and suggestions to edit my post for clarity.  I have made as much of these edits as I could.  I am new here, so please do comment below if you have any other suggestions or if I am missing some pertinent information.

***Final Addendum:***

One last update before I finish debugging for tonight.  I added a couple more optimizations that were not included in the [aforementioned script in the comment section](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/technical-guides/windows-powershell-scripts) which I had added because I knew from previous experiences [with this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlefiber/comments/5oucj2/how_to_get_actual_gigabit_speeds_when_wired_in/?st=k06u9gla&sh=d24248de) that involved TcpAckFrequency.  *I did not perform the change at the [interface level](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/328890/new-registry-entry-for-controlling-the-tcp-acknowledgment-ack-behavior) though - just the Tcpip/Parameter level.*  I even tried lowering the MTU to 1280 as apparently, CloudFlare did at one point [as shown in their blog](https://blog.cloudflare.com/increasing-ipv6-mtu/).

Final speedtest:

https://www.speedtest.net/result/8565346143 (about 105 Mbps)

The debugging grind really gets me at night. I happened to have an extra NIC lying around that I could put into my PC. Intel Gigabit CT Desktop Adapter. There are literally no updates for this driver since Windows 7 - it is an 11-year-old card. But, it's Gigabit. Well... as I plugged it in, I still got the same result. I have one last trick up my sleeve, and then I'm done.

Comment: Why does your title say 107?

Comment: I run it on Ookla speedtest from the Boston, MA Comcast server.  It goes from about 90Mbps, slowly up to around 106, just below 107 Mbps.  I don't know what it means....

Comment: What speed of service are you subscribed to from Xfinity?

Comment: I am on the 1.0 Gbps package.  Tested the copper and it reaches full speeds (got the copper and measuring device from Home Depot)

Comment: If I recall correctly, there is error correction and other overhead below the software layer so a 100mbps ethernet link can't achieve a full 100mpbs result on speed tests. If you're getting ~107 mbps, then I suspect you *are* connected at 1gbps on the ethernet link, and the bottleneck could be the Comcast hardware itself or something else.

Comment: @Romen Yeah, so I decided to perform the suggested [optimizations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/technical-guides/windows-powershell-scripts) using PowerShell.  Now here is my new test result:  https://www.speedtest.net/result/8565026460

Does that seem to fit?

Comment: So it went down from ~107 to 94 after running that script? Just to be sure, are other devices on your LAN getting better speed test results right now?

Comment: The driver on the ASUS website is from 2015 and it is EOL as of tomorrow, you should install the [latest driver from intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25016/Ethernet-Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-Windows-10?product=70831). In fact, Windows 10 may have automatically installed a *newer* driver when it was installed on your system!

Comment: I am testing my dual-boot laptop and I kid you not, speeds were about the same on Wifi and LAN on Windows.  But Linux had super high speeds.  This is extremely frustrating.

Comment: What model is your cable modem/gateway? What does its admin UI say about your DOCSIS WAN link? How many downstream channels is it using?

Comment: Spiff I believe it is DOCSIS 3.1 and has 34 downstream channels.

@Romen Surprisingly, updating it to the latest one does not make a difference.  Go figure, huh!

Edit: how did you deduce the EOL?

Edit 2: Model is... CGM4140COM and vendor is Technicolor.

Comment: Upon further investigation, I realized that the port is actually activated as 1.0 Gbps all around.  I saw a port as 100 Mbps but, apparently, this *is* my Vizo TV.  So, it is definitely not, at least officially, capped at 100 Mbps in any shape or form.  As far as I can tell, anyway.

Comment: @zinger, [Here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25104/Ethernet-Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-Windows-10) is the official 20.1 driver that ASUS mirrors on their website. See the first paragraph on the driver details. With Windows 10 you don't normally need to install most drivers from your motherboard disk or website. They are often older than the driver versions that Windows Update installs automatically.

Comment: @Romen Roger that!  Now I understand.

Just know that neither drivers made any differences.  I even checked my Xfinity account to make sure I paid my bill, so as to make sure it wasn't being throttled or something like that.  That is not the case.

So.....

I don't know.  I even tried lowering the MTU to 1280 [as apparently, CloudFlare did at one point](https://blog.cloudflare.com/increasing-ipv6-mtu/) as shown in the blog.  No dice.  (That was easily possible using the aforementioned script.)

Comment: Okay, one last update before I finish debugging for tonight.  I added a couple more optimizations that were not included in the script but I had added because I knew from previous experiences [with this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlefiber/comments/5oucj2/how_to_get_actual_gigabit_speeds_when_wired_in/?st=k06u9gla&sh=d24248de) that involved TcpAckFrequency.  *I did not perform the change at the [interface level](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/328890/new-registry-entry-for-controlling-the-tcp-acknowledgment-ack-behavior) though - just the Tcpip/Parameter level.* Read OP edits!

Comment: The debugging grind really gets me at night.  I happened to have an extra NIC lying around that I could put into my PC.  Intel Gigabit CT Desktop Adapter.  There are literally no updates for this driver since Windows 7 - it is a 11-year-old card.  But, it's Gigabit.  Well... as I plugged it in, I still got the same result.  I have one last trick up my sleeve, and then I'm done.

Comment: Can you update your answer with the actual upload AND download speeds for a) your WiFi b) your Linux system and c) your Windows system (no mention of upload speeds yet). You say that the Linux system has "super high speeds" but that's extremely vague. What speeds are you getting exactly?

Comment: You shouldn't have received downvotes for this. It's a perfectly valid question. Upvoted! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have the blinking orange LED indicator on my NIC as well as a solid green LED indicator. Apparently however, the blinking light would indicate just that the connection is established and is transmitting data whereas the solid LED is the speed.
>
> The speed LED does not blink, and is green.
>
> This would indicate my speed is being transmitted at 1.0 Gbps, right?

That's exactly [right](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1150/MAXIMUS-VI-HERO/E8459_Maximus_VI_Hero.pdf).

[image]

The steady green speed LED indicates that the NIC is running in full 1 Gbps mode. i.e. That the Ethernet cable and the device at the other end of it, your router, all support Gigabit Ethernet. (If the speed LED was orange, that would indicate 100 Mbps.)

> I am on a 1 Gbps plan with Comcast. It is a FTTC/N connection, so I use a coaxial splitter for cable and internet. I bought fresh coaxial for the internet and tested the speeds using a device I ordered from Home Depot. They reach maximum speeds on the copper.

You haven't mentioned exactly what speeds you are getting on your Linux system. "Super high speeds" is open to interpretation. Is it the full 1 Gbps that you pay for or less? How much less?

If none of your devices (laptops/tablets/cell phones, basically anything connected to the router) receive the full 1 Gbps speeds that you're paying for, you should temporarily bypass your splitter and re-run the speed test on multiple devices, to see if there is any improvement in the upload/download speeds at all. I've worked for cable companies before and bad splitters can absolutely affect internet speeds.

> I am testing my dual-boot laptop and I kid you not, speeds were about the same on Wifi and LAN on Windows. But Linux had super high speeds. This is extremely frustrating.

What's the fastest speed any device on your network is getting? Use the Ookla speed test app on your cell phone when connected to 5 GHz and see what upload and download speeds you get there, then let us know.

We first need to know that you're actually receiving the full 1 Gbps that you pay for (or at least exactly what speeds your other devices are getting), before we can effectively troubleshot the slow connection to one particular device.

> I even checked my Xfinity account to make sure I paid my bill, so as to make sure it wasn't being throttled or something like that.

Your cable company can only tell you what you're supposed to be getting, not what you're actually getting. The fastest speed you see on any device through a speed test tells you what speeds you're actually getting.

Again, please provide details about the actual upload and download speeds to other devices in your home, both wired and wireless, then bypass the splitter and run the speed tests again. Once we have some more information, it will be much easier to troubleshoot this effectively!